# peerinvalid Angular fire generator error

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, npm, bower

When i run npm install -g grunt-cli i get the following error

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package generator-angular does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-angularfire@0.0.6 wants generator-angular@~0.7.1

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/muhammadatif/Documents/tutorials/angular-101
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users//Documents/tutorials/angular-101/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this is a problem with `generator-angularfire` not been tested against the newer versions of `generator-angular`. You can read more about Peer Dependencies in NPM in this [official blog post](http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/02/07/peer-dependencies/).

What helped for me:

```
npm uninstall -g generator-angular
npm uninstall -g generator-karma
```

Then running again `npm install -g generator-angularfire` (or in your case: `npm install -g grunt-cli`) should solve the problem, because it will install older, compatible versions of the above 2 generators.